# Get current user in an OSGI context (Fuse, Karaf)

Tags: security, osgi, fuseesb, jbossfuse

In FUSE (or Karaf), how does one get the caller user id? I'm actually using FUSE with blueprint services.

For example, in a J2EE session bean, you can do:

sessionCtx.getCallerPrincipal()

Is there an equivalent in the OSGI service space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Karaf we use plain jaas to do service authentication. So you can use the following code to access the subject and principals.

```
AccessControlContext acc = AccessController.getContext();
Subject subject = Subject.getSubject(acc);
Set<Principal> principals = subject.getPrincipals();
```

In karaf 3 there is also built in [role based access control for OSGi services](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/users-guide/security.html). So you can define which roles may access which services.

Comment: Thank you. I found lots of information about how to set up JAAS, but could not find a simple code snippet of how to use it at runtime to get the principle. This is exactly what I was looking for.